# Trouble calling one method into another

Tags: java, loops

I have a program that deals with using different loops in different methods. The program as a whole is working fine apart from one method that calls another.

I am having trouble with a method that calls another.

What I want to do is:

1. Have the method call the other and run it which takes a variable
   from the user (1 - 100).
2. Increment a variable if an invalid input is
   entered.
3. Display a message and exit back to menu when 3 inputs are
   entered in a row.

The method that is being called works fine on it's own and it works when I call it.

What I can't get to work is the display message when after 3 invalid inputs. At present, it takes about 7 invalid inputs then it displays the message??

Method that works:

```
public static boolean processGrade(int percentMark)
{
    Menu m = new Menu();
    clrscr();
    System.out.println("Please enter your mark e.g. 90. (input -1 to exit): "); 
    percentMark = Genio.getInteger();
    if
    (percentMark >=70 && percentMark <=100)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Your Grade is A - Excellent!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
    }
    else if(percentMark >= 60 && percentMark <70)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Your Grade is B - Good!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
    }
    else if (percentMark >=50 && percentMark <60)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("Your Grade is C - Ok!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
    }
    else if(percentMark >=40 && percentMark <50)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println(" Your Grade is D - Must Do Better!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
    }
    else if (percentMark <40 && percentMark >= 0 )
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println(" Your Grade is E - Must Do Better!\n\n");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
    }
    else if (percentMark < -1 || percentMark >100)
    {
        clrscr();
        System.out.println("ERROR: Value MUST be in the range of 0 - 100!");
        pressKey();
        clrscr();
        return false;
    }
    else if (percentMark == -1)
    {
        //clrscr();
        System.out.println("You entered -1, you will now return to the menu!");
        pressKey();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Method that I can't get to work that calls the above message:

```
public static void processGradeV2(int percentMark)
{
    int invalid = 0;
    outerloop:
    do {   
        clrscr();
        boolean result = processGrade(percentMark);
        processGrade(percentMark);// Call processGrade method

        if(result == false)
        {
            invalid++;
        }
        if(invalid == 3)
        {
            clrscr();
            System.out.println("Sorry, you have entered an invalid integer 3 times in a row! The program will return to the menu screen.");
            pressKey();
            break outerloop;
            //return;
        } 
        if(percentMark == -1)
        {
            clrscr();
            System.out.println("You entered -1, you will now return to the menu!");
            pressKey();
            clrscr();
            break outerloop;
            //processUserChoices();
        }
    }
    while(invalid <3);
 }
```

Comment: Does this even compile? . For starters processGrade(percentMark) has a void return type rather than boolean but you expect a boolean to be returned? boolean result = processGrade(percentMark)

Comment: Sorry, that was a pasting error. I have edited the code. Would the whole code be helpful? I know a lot of people hate when anyone posts too much code. It is 3 classes, not too much.

Comment: Info: there is no need for labels here. Try to avoid them. And why do you call `processGrade(percentMark)` twice? Still a "pasting error"?

Comment: As @Tom mentioned, remove the labels and try it out.

Comment: I didn't realise I did call it twice? I assign a variable that holds the method so I can set it to true or flase. Does that count as calling it? Please appreciate that I am a beginner. Thanks

Comment: A variable can't hold a method. This is Java a not a functional language. This line `boolean result = processGrade(percentMark);` calls the method `processGrade` and "writes" the returned value to the variable `result`.

Comment: Yes, assining it to a var is the way to call it, because its return type is not void.

Comment: Thank you. This was where I was getting it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
processGrade(percentMark);// Call processGrade method
```

will cause you a problem here, delete it.

You already assigned the `processGrade(percentMark);` result to the `result` variable.

Comment: The second call causes the increased number of inputs, before it exits the do/while loop. (Just as an addtitional information)

Comment: That was it... as simple as that. Thank you very much! I feel silly for not realising that assigning the class to a variable was actually calling it too. Learned something new, thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

I would delete `boolean result = processGrade(percentMark)` and instead change your if statement to:

```
 if(!processGrade(percentMark)){
     invalid++;
 }
```